# How do I use Instrumentation to replace a source code file?

Tags: java, function, class, methods, instrumentation

I am trying to replace a class at runtime using `Instrumentation.redefineClasses`. (don't ask why) I have two questions:

- How do I get a copy of the `Instrumentation` class in my `main` method? The documentation says something about `agent - jar` that I don't understand.
- What is the bytes parameter for in `ClassDefinition`? Is it the string you are trying to replace the class with converted to an array of bytes, or something else? So if I want to replace the class `Foo.java` with the following text:

  ```
  public class Foo {
    public int Bar(){
      return 0;
    } 
  }
  ```

  What would be the correct array of bytes to put in `new ClassDefinition(Foo.class, bytes here)`?

Comment: Hello, anybody here? Is this forum inactive?

Comment: Instrumentation works on compiled *byte code*, not source code. That’s why you receive a byte array containing the code and have to return a byte array containing the changed code. You don’t get an instance of an `Instrumentation` implementation in the `main` method; as [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html#package.description) explains, a Java Agent is a different software launched either before or alongside your main application and will be started via its `premain` or `agentmain` method which can receive an `Instrumentation`.